# CSV engine on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, csv, mysql5.5

I don't think that this is a programming question so I am going to ask it here -

Reading the book high performance mysql, I read about the CSV engine. The paragraph says:

> The CSV engine can treat comma-separated values (CSV) files as table,
>   but it does not support indexes on them. This engine lets you copy
>   files in and out of the database while the server is running. If you
>   export a CSV file from a spreadsheet and save it in the MySQL server's
>   data directory, the server can read it immediately. Similary, if you
>   write data to a CSV table, an external program can read it right away.
>   CSV tables are especially useful as a data interchange format and for
>   certain kinds of logging.

What I get from this paragraph is that I can copy a .CSV file into the data directory of database, and it should show as a table that is able to be read from. However, whenever I copy a test .csv file into the directory, it does not appear as a table. I can't access it.

I am using MySQL 5.5 also

Does anyone know why this is not working, or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I opted to try this out on my MySQL server to see what the problem was.  It appears that you need to create the table in MySQL (with engine=csv specified) so that the table will appropriately be added to MySQL and it will keep track of the table field metadata.  In my testing, I was unable to make MySQL learn of the csv file without first using "create table."

Example:

1. Create new csv named foo in this example a column named "i" for an integer, and "c" for a character field:
   `CREATE TABLE foo (i int not null, c char(10) not null) engine=csv;`
2. foo.frm, foo.CSM, foo.CSV are created in /var/lib/mysql/data/dbname, you will note that foo.CSV is zero-byte.
3. Copy your existing csv (that matches the format defined for the table) into foo.CSV:

   ```
   1,"FOOBAR"
   2,"FOOBAZ"
   3,"BARBAZ"
   ```
4. In mysql, select * from foo should produce the following result:

   ```
   mysql> select * from foo;
   +---+--------+
   | i | c      |
   +---+--------+
   | 1 | FOOBAR |
   | 2 | FOOBAZ |
   | 3 | BARBAZ |
   +---+--------+
   3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```

Comment: So for example, you created a csv file with test data called 'test.csv', then CREATE TABLE test ENGINE=csv; and it was able to read the data from the test.csv like a normal table?

Comment: What I did was create table, which created a csv file in the data directory.  I then copied over my csv into that filename and was able to do queries.